# grep strings based on the length

Tags: bash, grep

Is it possible to search strings based on the length in a specific file using grep?

I have tried using the awk but did not work

```
awk '$0~"^s" && length($0)==31' strings.xml
```

If not using grep is it possible to find using some other command line tool.

Comment: Please provide sampe input and the desired output/result.

Comment: Please explain "did not work". In which way did it not achieve as desired? False positives? False negatives? Crash? Hang?

Comment: I was not able to get the results. I know for sure that there is 31-byte string existing

Comment: Agree with both comments. For start, you can try the awk with each of the conditions alone (^s and length) to see which one fails. In general, do $0 ~ /^s/ (no quotes)

Comment: You will have to show us a line that you think it augt to be detecting, and p[erhaps one that it should not detect?

Comment: The command in your question, though not optimal, **WILL** find lines that start with `s` and are 31 characters long. If it's not finding them in your input then **they don't exist in your input**. Maybe your input file has DOS line endings and so has invisible `\r` or something in the lines so what looks like 31 chars is really 32 - try `cat -v file` to see if that's the case and if so remove them with `dos2unix` or similar.

Comment: Please show us some part of your input. We need examples to help understand what you want, how to achieve it and why the line you show does not work. Please show us at least one line which you would want to be found by the command and one line which you would NOT want to be found by the command.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
grep -E '^s.{30}$' strings.xml
```

The regexp matches `s` at the beginning of the line, followed by any 30 characters, then the end of the line. So it will match a line with exactly 31 characters beginning with `s`.

But the `awk` command is equivalent, so if it didn't work, neither will this.

Answer (score 0):

`awk` default is to split fields by whitespace, therefore if you want to match against the first match starting with `s` and have a length of 31, you could use:

```
awk '$1 ~ /^s.{30}$/ {print}' strings.xml
```

The `/^s` is to match a string starting with `s` and the `.{30}$` matches any `.` character (except for line terminators) `{30}` exactly 30 times

Comment: That would find lines of length 527 for example.

Comment: hi @EdMorton could you please enlighten me here, I don't get the 527?

Comment: I just picked a number greater than 31. The point is that regexp will match lines of length 31 **or greater** not just lines of length 31 and it also won't "match any `.` **up to** `30` characters" - that'd be `.{1,30}`.